# why is the hint in my editText too close to top border?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-edittext

I have the following xml:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lableText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"        
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:text="Password"
    android:textColor="#516063"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textStyle="italic" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/inputText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.7"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/input_box_idle"
    android:hint="Your Password"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:textColor="#516063"
    android:textColorHint="#b4c8cf"
    android:textSize="20dp" />
```

which brings this ui:

[image]

Why is is the hint in my editText too close to top border?

the textView is much closer to the bottom, but non of them has bottom margins or paddings.

Comment: Is @drawable/input_box_idle a 9 patch image?

Comment: yes it is. how can it work

Comment: If 'input_box_idle' is a 9-patch, change the EditText bg to a color (red - for testing-) if the hint appear correctly, then you have a problem with the 9patch

Comment: I used your code seems fine didn't use the image though so may be the problem with your image.

Comment: The fill area of your 9-patch image may be causing this issue.The fill area may not allow any content outside its bounds.Check the 9-patch using the 9 patch editor provided by sdk

Comment: you're right. but how can the bg effect the hint position?

Comment: Pls show your full xml code..

Comment: If you dont set the 9patch content (right and bottom), i Think the scale area become a content area. set the content to be centred like this example http://developer.android.com/images/draw9patch-bad.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `EditText` is a `9-patch` (drawable/input_box_idle), first try to replace the Background with a Color. If the hint appear correctly (centred vertically) then you have a problem with your `9-patch`.

Mostly its a problem with the content area (right and bottom). If you haven’t set a content area i think android will use the scale area as a content area.

See this image example and try to make the content area cantered like it. (check `show content` in the 9-patch tool to see the content - the blue area).
[image]